# Infrastructure as Code for Bitbucket Repos?

Tags: bitbucket, infrastructure-as-code

Is there a way to create and configure BitBucket (Cloud) pipelines and advanced repo configuration options with "infrastructure as code" tools (in the genre of cloudformation, terraform, pulumi, etc.)?

It looks like Terraform has some support, but I'm looking for something more advanced: things like the ability to set repository deployment and variable settings and possibly even set up pipelines. It looks like Bitbucket has quite an extensive REST api for some of these features already. But I don't see any obvious wrappers in the "infrastructure as code" space.

Comment: Maybe you can check this: https://www.north-47.com/knowledge-base/how-we-deploy-with-terraform-and-bitbucket-to-azure-kubernetes/

Comment: @f.trajkovski thanks for the link. It looks like they are using BB as a code repo and pipeline service, but what I am interested is automating the *creation and configuration of Bitbucket repositories and pipelines using code*. Similar to some of what is available in AWS in Cloudformation/Terraform/etc (though if I remember right AWS's CodeCommit automation is limited mostly to creation).

Answer (score 2):

There is very limited code as infrastructure support for bitbucket repos in terraform. It does support creating repositories and setting repository variables. Unfortunately there is no support for deployments. You can see provider details on:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/bitbucket/index.html

Alternative solution is to use directly bitbucket api:

https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/